# Make sure function cannot be called during tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

First of all: Feel free to tell me that this is an antipattern!

In my code, I have some functions responsible for calling external API's. This is a prime candidate for mocking in the tests to make sure that the external API is not hit when tests are run.

The thing is, the way mocking works in python (at least the way I have been taught), we mock a position in the imported module structure explicitly, e.g.

```
import mymodule

def test_api():
    mocker.patch('mymodule.mysubmodule.json_apis.my_api_wrapper_function')
    [...]
```

This will mock out the `my_api_wrapper_function` function for the test. However, what if refactoring moves the function or renames it, etc.? If the test is not updated, it will most likely pass, AND the external API is hit, because the new location of the function has not been mocked.

I see two solutions to this question, but I am not sure how to implement any of them

- Mock stuff in a better way, so that I am sure not to have problems when refactoring
- Create a decorator, which will wrap a function and raise an exception if the function is called in a test context (I suppose this depends on the test runner that is used? In my case, it is `pytest`)

Comment: Logically, this will always be a problem - if you're testing against a mock of an external system, and the external system changes, your code will fail but your tests will continue to pass *because your mock no longer reflects it*. You will need to have an integration testing step that ensures that your code still works against the external API, which you can run less frequently than the unit-testing against the mocked API.

Comment: In that case, the integration test would still need mocking. No test can ever hit the API. Imagine the external system is a customer service application, and the API calls are for creating, commenting on and closing tickets. This should never happen during any tests

Comment: Then that's a problem that can't be solved by automated testing alone. At some stage, you need to either have a way to ensure that the mock reflects the external service, or accept that occasional failures will occur in production when the external service changes in ways you haven't accounted for.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. How about the solution about forcing specific function calls to break tests (e.g. with a decorator)? It seems sorta silly to let test configuration bleed into the code, but it would solve the problem 100%. Care to comment on that? Anything I haven't thought of?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem that solves. If you're mocking out the API wrapper, there should be no way that any call on that mock would end up calling the API. Rather than mocking out individual methods/functions, mock out the whole wrapper class/module.

Comment: It solves the issue that when mocks are incorrectly written - for arbitrary reasons - there is a failsafe to make sure that API calls won't succeed, and the failing test will indicate that the mocking is incorrect rather than the code is incorrect.
As you imply, the issue could also be solved by convention of putting API calls in a specific module and always mock that entire module during tests. Then if the module is moved, we know that ALL tests need review. That is actually a good enough answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all the sentence

> If the test is not updated, it will most likely pass, AND the external API is hit, because the new location of the function has not been mocked.

is **wrong**.

If you try to mock something that not exist and you don't use `create=True` attribute the patch fail!

```
>>> from mock import patch
>>> patch("doesnt.exist").start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 1396, in start
    result = self.__enter__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 1252, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 1414, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 1098, in _importer
    thing = __import__(import_path)
ImportError: No module named doesnt
```

Moreover if you use some good refactoring tool like the one integrated in PyCharm it will fix the string path too when you move something.

Comment: you are correct. Only things that exist can be mocked. However, the same piece of code can exist in many places when importing. Imagine three modules a, b, and c, when b has `from c import myfunc` and a has `from b import myfunc`. This is completely valid, and mocking one of those references will not affect the other. This might be part of the problem. Imports should be kept clean.

Comment: If you want patch `myfunc` in `a` or `b` you MUST patch the `a` and `b` reference and not the original one otherwise `a` and `b` will continue to use the unpatched version.

Comment: exactly. So maybe the issue I am having is due to tangled imports.

Comment: IMHO the best is write your wrapper (that is always a good practice) but mock the library: if you mock the library you will free to change your wrapper and update your mock only when you change the library.